# How come JPG images runs ok in local browsers but not in Google Map on-line?

Tags: javascript, maps, png, jpeg

I have a Google Map application that we are trying to host it on Google Map's site.
The application work fine on my local web browsers, IE, Firefox, Chrome...etc, but when I upload the same application with the image file paths modified for the Google site; some of the JPG files loads, but the majority of them does not. That's also including some small .PNG files.  I am a beginner programmer in Javascript, could some one tells me what's going on???
Please help...
My Codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.4, user-scalable=YES" />
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
       </style>
   <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCyGkoZ07Vr67PDxHpbgD0Zxb-oP6-wqH8sensor=true">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.011164, -113.039978);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions:
                    {style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.MEDIUM}
     };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://sites.google.com/site/leastcostpath/home/AOI_70.kmz?attredirects=0&d=1');
    georssLayer.setMap(map);
    var compPos = new google.maps.LatLng(50.611833, -113.622775);

///***  Logo files does not load, work okay in local browsers  *** ///      
            var compLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt/home/prjmap/Goosecreeklogo.png',
        new google.maps.Size(60,40),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(-60,40)
        );
        var compMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: compPos,
        map: map,
        icon: compLogo,
        title:"Goosecreek - Blackie"
    });

    var ctyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.802294, -112.577147);
    var ctyLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt/home/prjmap/starlandlogo.png',
        new google.maps.Size(62,20),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(-40,20)
        );
        var ctyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ctyPos,
        map: map,
        icon: ctyLogo,
        title:"Starland County"
    });

///  Site info   ////
   //M_Deli1
    var latLng_Deli1 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.6320281, -112.3740475);
    var contentString_Deli1 ='<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice"></div><div </a>
           <img src="../Starlandlogo.JPG" </div><H2>Delia Hockey Rink</H2> <p>5KW Side-Mount
     System<br /><br /> Panel: 21 Sharp 230W panels<br /> Inverter: Enphase Energy<br />
 </p><div </a><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt/home/prjmap/
    Delia_Arena.JPG" alt="5KW System"/ > <br /></div>';
    var infowindow_Deli1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString_Deli1
    });
    var marker_Deli1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng_Deli1,
        map: map,
        title:"Delia Hockey Rink"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_Deli1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow_Deli1.open(map, marker_Deli1);
});

///................   lots more site follows  ...............//
 }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Comment: Is the html just word-wrapping here in stackoverflow or is that a line break in the filename? You cannot use line breaks in filenames.

Comment: Hi.  No.  It's just word wrapping.  I cannot post it without inserting the spaces, as your Coding area does not accept it as "Proper Coding".  There's no line breaks in my actual code......

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  --Andrew.

Comment: Hello, Anyone has any comments?? Please......Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you host this somewhere so we can debug it on a browser?

Comment: Hi Edson, I have sent this out before, not sure whether you received it.

Comment: It's hosted at :  https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt.   I will try to correct the file name cases so see if thsi is the issue, but I have a feeling that the suggested solution from Justin and Quentin is not the roof of the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The filename case is wrong. You should use:

https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt/home/prjmap/GooseCreekLogo.png

instead of:

https://sites.google.com/site/goosecreekgbt/home/prjmap/Goosecreeklogo.png

and same for the other images.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much Edson.  I guess I am so used to the Windows (PC)'s file naming and forgot about the differences in the UNIX/Linux world.......It's now working just fine.....Thanks again.  One more question if you don't mind...If I want to add logo(s) at the lower right hand corner of the map; which follows the user where-ever he zoom in or out, what would be the most efficient and easiest way to do this in terms of coding in Javascript...???  Thanks and please advise.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When hosted filenames are case sensitive, when local they are not. So, `.JPG` is not the same as `.jpg`.

Comment: You can have case sensitive local filesystems. You can have case insensitive hosted filesystems.

Comment: @Quentin - You can, but its not as common. Windows and OSX by default are case insensitive and Linux, BSD, etc. by default are. Most hosted servers fall into the Linux, BSD, etc. group, most local systems fall into the Windows and OSX group. -- Yes I know many local systems are Linux, but its not as common as Windows/OSX combined. And yes I know OSX is a BSDish system.